# How to get span id from innerHTML

Tags: jquery, html

My need is very simple and I am not getting any way yet. 
I have JQuery object 'node' which contains div id. When I write below code:-

```
alert($(node).get(0).innerHTML)
```

I get result as following:-

```
<div><span id="spn_148">ABC</span></div>
```

I only want to get span id i.e "spn_148" from innerHTML of $(node). Please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `span` id like this:

```
$(node).find('span')[0].id
```

Bracket `[0]` is the equivalent to `.get(0)` in your example, just shorter. So the idea is to find `span` element withing `node` and get its `id` property.

Comment: or `.attr("id")` without the [0]